# Android InputStream flush from Bluetooth adapter

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, inputstream

My [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) is listening for a character to be sent from my phone to print sensor data to send back via a [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) module. This is working fine and the communication is fast and accurate. However, the problem occurs when I request data from two different sensors.

I will request data from sensor A and get my results fine. I then request data from sensor B, and I get what seems to be a leftover request to sensor A and get information from sensor A again. I can request data from sensor B twice in a row, and I will then receive data from sensor B accurately.

I have tried to flush the input stream, but that made my application crash. I also tried to use InputStream.wait() and then interrupt the wait with InputStream.notify() when requesting data from a different sensor. This also crashed the program.

This is my receive code. The character that is being passed in is the character that defines what sensor data to send back from the Arduino.

```
public String receive(Character c) {
    try {
        myOutputStream.write(c);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final byte delimiter = 10; // ASCII code for a newline
        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
                        && !stopWorker) {

                    try {

                        int bytesAvailable = myInputStream.available();
                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            myInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0,
                                            encodedBytes, 0,
                                            encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(
                                            encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            status = data;
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ex) {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        myThread.start();
        return (status);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        status = "Failed";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (status);
}
```

This is some of the Arduino code, and it is very simple.

```
if(bluetooth.available()) //If something was sent from phone
{
    char toSend = (char)bluetooth.read(); //Reads the char sent
    if (toSend == 'T')
    {
      //If the char is T, turn on the light.
      float voltage = analogRead(14) * 5.04;
      voltage /= 1024.0;
      float temperatureC = (voltage - .5) * 100;
      float temperatureF = (temperatureC * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0;
      bluetooth.println(temperatureF);
}
```

How can I fix this problem?